# How to dynamically load TailwindCSS classes in Nuxt 3

Tags: tailwind-css, nuxt3

I am working on a Nuxt 3 app which should enable the user to adjust a Nuxt 3 example component with every possible Tailwind CSS class and showcase how it would look like.

However I am facing the problem now, that only Tailwind CSS classes which I already use for styling the app itself are accepted and others are not loaded.

How can I navigate this problem?